# Хранение состояния сессии

Tags: golang, javascript, php

Я новичок в вебе. Как и где хранить информацию о пользователе между запросами к серверу? Как я понимаю, надо хранить в куках (не на сервере же)? Или это не безопасно?

**Обновление** Мне интересен механизм работы. Я пишу на `Go`, там библиотек не много. Задача: реализовать работу с несколькими типами пользователей. Нашел тип `Cookie`. Сейчас реализую механизм отслеживания пользователя через них.

Comment: go? &mdash;

Comment: Используйте серверное хранилище данных, обычно это БД ^^<br>
<b>"не на сервере же"</b> ЛОЛ а где еще?

Answer (score 1):

На мой взгляд, лучше использовать готовое решение. Существует отличная библиотека [gorilla](http://gorilla-web.appspot.com/). Из личного опыта могу сказать, что работает приемлемо, есть нарекания на счет двух хранилищ данных.

Answer (score 0):

используйте [session_start](http://ua.php.net/session_start) а затем,

```
$_SESSION['myUserName'] = 'Пупкин';
```

Вот и всё, теперь в переменной $_SESSION будет запись о myUserName

Comment: Вопрос о текущем состоянии сессии как я понял, т.е. чтобы после закрытия браузера состояние оставалось тем-же

Comment: **Как и где хранить информацию о пользователе между запросами к серверу?**

лично я понял это несколько иначе ...